# how to generate custom 403 HTTP responses in Plone (prevent redirect)

Tags: python, plone

Upon unauthorized access, Plone by default provides a redirect to login form. I need to prevent this for certain subpaths (ie. not globally), and instead return 403 Forbidden, with a custom (short) HTML page, after the (otherwise) normal Plone authentication & authorization has taken place.

I looked into ITraversable but using that takes place too early in the request processing chain - ie. before auth etc.

One possible yet unexplored method is having a custom view injected to URL path that performs auth checks on the object that maps to the remaining subpath. So there could be a request with URL something like `http://myplone/somepath/customview/withcustom403`, where:

1. The `customview` view implements `IPublishTraverse`, and its `publishTraverse()` returns itself
2. The same view then next validates, in its `__call__` method, the access to `withcustom403` object, ie. by calling `getSecurityManager().validate()`
3. If validation fails, the view sets response to 403 and returns the custom HTML

Would this work? Or is there some event triggered after auth takes place, but before Plone calls `response.Unauthorized()` (triggering redirect), that would provide a cleaner solution?

This is for current Plone 4.3.4.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351610/make-plone-give-proper-403-forbidden-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new PAS Challenge plugin based on the acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth plugin and make sure to move it to the top of the Challenge plugins in acl_users.

Or maybe use a monkey patch to change the current plugin.  For demonstration purposes only, you can edit `Products/PluggableAuthService/plugins/CookieAuthHelper.py`.  In the `unauthorized` method, you will see these lines:

```
url = '%s%scame_from=%s' % (url, sep, quote(came_from))
resp.redirect(url, lock=1)
```

Before those lines, add two lines to prevent unauthorized access to any resource that has `nogo` in its url:

```
if 'nogo' in came_from:
    return 1
```

If you create your own plugin, check the `setupAuthPlugins` function in `Products/PlonePAS/Extensions/Install.py` for a way to install it if you do not want to do it by hand.

Comment: BTW there's now a PAS plugin that only redirects to login form if the UA is a browser: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/koodaamo.pas.browseronlyredirect/

Answer (score 0):

You could override `Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_login/require_login.py` and add any logic that you want there to give a custom response.

Or bypass `require_login` completely and use an own browser view to handle this.  In your Plone Site go to `acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth/manage_propertiesForm` and for the Login Form property replace `require_login` with your browser view name.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However it seems the redirect has at this point already taken place?

Comment: True. Let me suggest another approach in a different answer.